# open google map from flutter app using place_id

Tags: android, flutter, google-maps

```dart
class MapUtility {
  static Future<void> openLocation(String placeId) async {
    Uri googleUrl =
        Uri.parse('https://www.google.com/maps/place/?q=place_id:$placeId');
    if (!await launchUrl(googleUrl)) {
      throw Exception("Could not open google map");
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to open google map using place id but it doesn't work with android. In ios the map opens perfectly with the place selected. But in android I get
`place_id:<place's id>` in the search field.

screenshot from and android device:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use map_launcher flutter to launch google maps with place_id.

Take a look to extra params [here](https://github.com/mattermoran/map_launcher/issues/14#issuecomment-784200255).

Edit : Don't forget to follow url guide [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/get-started)

Comment: what's the difference? I mean why is url_launcher not working?

Comment: i think because map_launcher follow [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/get-started?hl=en#forming-the-url)

Answer (score 0):

Hiii! I was having the same problem, so I tried **changing the maps Id by the title and a short address of the place** and it worked.

You can get the title and address using `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json`

The idea is to make it unmistakable for maps to find it. I hope it helps :)

```dart
'https://www.google.com/maps/place/?q=$name $address'
```

This is the full code:

```dart
openRestaurantInMaps(Restaurant restaurant) async {
  final String? url = restaurant.getGoogleMapsUrl();
  final uri = Uri.parse(url!);
  if (await canLaunchUrl(uri)) await launchUrl(uri);
}

// Restaurant class
String? getGoogleMapsUrl() {
  if (googleMapsId == null) return null;
  return 'https://www.google.com/maps/place/?q=$name $address';
}
```